# Text file clearing itself when program is run again

Tags: python

I made a program that allows the user to create an account. It seemed to work until I tried the login feature, which kept alerting me that the username and password do not exist. When I re-run the program and create an account, the txt file has my given name and password inside. However when I close the program and reopen it to run the login feature the name and password are no longer there. Any ideas on how to fix this?

PS: I'm rather new to all of this and if there is anything i could/should have done instead please let me know.

```
while True:
    #Account file and same file as list.
    AccountsFile = open("AccountProj.txt", "w+")
    AccountList = [line.split(',') for line in AccountsFile.readlines()]
    
    #Creates an account 
    def createaccount():
        while True:
            
            newname = (input("Please create a username: "))
            
            if newname in AccountsFile:
                print("Username already in use.")
                continue
            
            elif newname not in AccountsFile:

                newpassword = input("Please create a password: ")

                checkpassword = input("Re-enter password: ")
            
                if checkpassword == newpassword:
                    print("Account Sucessesfuly created!")
                    AccountsFile.write(newname + "\n")
                    AccountsFile.write(checkpassword + "\n")
                    AccountsFile.close()
                    break

                elif checkpassword != newpassword:
                    print("Passwords do not match")
                    continue
    #Logs into an account
    def loginaccount():
        while True:
            
            username_entry = input("Enter username: ")
            
            if username_entry not in AccountList:
                print("Username not found. Please enter a valid name")
                continue
            elif username_entry in AccountList:
                password_entry = input("Enter password: ")
                
                if password_entry in AccountList[AccountList.index(username_entry) + 1]:
                    print("Login sucessful!")
                    AccountsFile.close()
                    break
                if password_entry not in AccountList[AccountList.index(username_entry) + 1]:
                    print("Username and password do not match. Please try again.")
                    AccountsFile.close()
                    continue

                
    #Asks if user wants to create or login to an account            
    loginchoice = input("Would you like to login? (Y/N) ")
    
    if loginchoice in ('Y', 'N'):
    
        if loginchoice == 'Y':
            loginaccount()

        if loginchoice == 'N':
            
            createchoice = str(input("Would you like to create an account? (Y/N) "))
            
            if createchoice in ('Y', 'N'):
            
                if createchoice == 'Y':
                    createaccount()

                if createchoice == 'N':
                    exit()
            break
    else:
        print("Invalid Input")
```

Comment: Off-topic programming tip: Don't put those function definitions in your `while True:` loop as there is no need to do it repeatively. Define them separately before and outside the loop that's calling them.

Comment: I reading this on my smartphone so it’s hard to read your code but did you close the file? Maybe use the '''with''' syntax. 

https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-343.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You opened your file in `w+` mode, this will override your previous content because it starts writing right at the beginning of the file.

Instead, you should use the `a` mode for *appending* your text to any previously written content.

See: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files:

*(...) mode can be 'r' when the file will only be read, 'w' for only writing (an existing file with the same name will be erased), and 'a' opens the file for appending; any data written to the file is automatically added to the end.*

Comment: I got the file to save properly, so thank you. However despite the names being in the file, it still says it cannot find the name in the file. Would you know how to fix it? I also moved the functions to the outside of the while loop and changed the mode to 'a+'

Comment: Take a look into your file, I guess you are not writing the usernames as you expect it?
You split your fily by `,`, but you never write a comma as far as I can see